# "Chunking" a streaming algorithm in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Previously, in imperative languages, I have used closures to calculate data lazily, like this (example in psuedo-JavaScript):

```
var montecarlo_pi = function() {
    all = 0;
    hits = 0;
    return function() {
         if (sqrt(random()^2 + random()^2) <= 1) hits++;
         all++;
         return 4*hits/all;
    }
}
pi_estimate = montecarlo_pi();
```

Every call to pi_estimate returns a number which gets closer and closer to pi. This assembly lets me do some cool stuff like plotting the values on a graph, or doing analysis on how fast the number approximates pi.

I have written a couple of monte carlo methods to approximate pi in haskell too; most notably one using Data.Conduit. In Conduit, I generate some number of random numbers using Data.Conduit.Combinators.sourceRandomN, and calculate "hits" in the "lengthIf" sink. (I have also done this using a strict fold over a list of random numbers.)

I am wondering how I can break up the calculation, and perhaps more generally apply a streaming data algorithm to some chunk of data at a time.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself?  How much of the Haskell language do you understand?  Just providing you with a solution doesn't strike me as very educational.

Comment: Maybe you can post the code you already have using Conduits - then we have a starting-point to help you (maybe this is your starting point(?): https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2014/03/monte-carlo-haskell - if so just say it ;) )

Comment: The `pipes-group` library solves the problem of breaking streams into sub-streams and has some examples in [Pipes.Group.Tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group-1.0.1/docs/Pipes-Group-Tutorial.html), but it's not clear to me whether or not that is what you are asking.

Comment: From the sound of it you can just use a `scanl` to get a lazy infinite list that approximates `pi`.  Would that suffice or is there something I'm missing here?